# Find the volume

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, volume, rotations

Find the volume formed by rotating the region enclosed by $x = 36y$ and $y^3 = x$ with $y \ge 0$ about the y-axis .

**My try** : We can conclude from the conditions that $x=0 $ , $y = 0$ , $x = 6^3$ and $y = 6$ . So the answer is a cylinder with $r = 6^3$ , $h = 6$ and the volume is $6^7 \times \pi$ .

Is my answer right ? If not , what's the solution ?

Comment: I don’t think it is a cylinder! Let draw a sketch for the two functions and find intersection points.

Comment: @gimusi The intersection points form a rectangle . When it rotates about y-axis , the result is a cylinder .

Comment: Did you plot a sketch?

Comment: Yes : https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%3D0+,+y%3D0+,+x+%3D+216+,+y+%3D+6

Comment: You need to plot the functions.

Comment: Okay , what's the next step ? https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%3D+36y+and+y%5E3+%3D+x

Comment: The right wing rotates about the $y-$axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Find the intersection point $x=a>0$ then by the [shell method](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/VolumeWithCylinder.aspx) the set up is

$$V=\int_0^a 2\pi x\left(\sqrt[3] x-\frac x {36}\right) dx$$

Comment: Very nice , thanks a lot .

Comment: @S.H.W You are very welcome! Bye